# How can I make my S3 bucket non-public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I have a bucket at s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-123 which is public. 
I can access it via a browser, even when I'm not authenticated; it shows an xml page with all the links to my files, even though I have this policy in the bucket :

```
  {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "*"
              },
              "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket123"
          },
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "*"
              },
              "Action": [
                  "s3:PutObject",
                  "s3:GetObject",
                  "s3:DeleteObject"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket123/*"
          }
      ]
  }
```

I think this policy might be set up in a wrong way.

What I want is

a) make it non-public

and

b) allow my python script to work with it via API, regardless of the IP address. The script uses the standard cli "aws s3" utility of Amazon and an API key.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your principal statements: `"AWS": "*"` is making the S3 bucket public. Instead if you specify an account number that you own, the bucket will not be public anymore. However, for your use case, you should lock the access using the IAM user and remove the bucket policy completely.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR, how exactly?

Comment: Create an inline policy in your IAM user and add the following: `{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Sid":"Stmt1513781170000","Effect":"Allow","Action":["s3:ListBucket"],"Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket123"]},{"Sid":"Stmt1513781170000","Effect":"Allow","Action":["s3:DeleteObject","s3:GetObject","s3:PutObject"],"Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket123/*"]}]}`

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR, what's "inline policy"?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR and where can I find "Stmt15137811700‌​00" for my account exactly?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR, what's "inline policy"?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all S3 buckets and objects are private. Now, you are using a bucket policy with "Principal": {"AWS": "*"}  which makes it "public". Usually, we should use bucket policy if we want to give access to another AWS account or achieve more granular permissions. If you are trying to access the bucket from the same account, bucket policy might not be required.

So, to make it private, you can just [delete the bucket policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html) and give necessary permission via IAM e.g. if your script is using access keys of an IAM user, you should attach an [IAM permission policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html) (e.g. S3FullAccess) to the user.

Also, ["Sid"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_sid.html) is an optional identifier used in the policy, so you can use anything or even omit it in IAM/S3 bucket policy.

Comment: `if your script is using access keys of an IAM user, ` --> how can I find this out?

Comment: @Kakki If you are using IAM user's access keys or running the script on an EC2 instance with IAM role attached with proper permissions, you should be able to to make access S3 bucket/object from any IP if you have not used "aws:SourceIP" condition. Could you please share if there is any error you are getting?

Comment: `If you are using IAM user's access keys ` --> how can I find  out whether or not I am using them?

Comment: How you are accessing AWS resources? If you are using SDK or AWS CLI, you have to configure with access keys and you have to check your script where you are getting the credentials (access keys) from.

Comment: `How you are accessing AWS resources? ` --> my script uploads  files to S3

Comment: `you have to configure with access keys and you have to check your script where you are getting the credentials (access keys) from` --> how exactly?